# How do I re-issue OpenSSL snakeoil cert?

Tags: openssh

In light of the recent heartbleed fiasco and whatnot I too have been scrambling to up security on some servers. My question is how do I reissue the Snakeoil cert that comes with Openssl?

The cert that it is currently using was issued in 2012, so clearly before this incident. So it seems like the protocol here is to reissue all certs and I cant find info on how to do so for snakeoil.

I am the only one who uses that cert, for PHPmyadmin, so do I even need to update it?

Comment: You do know why it is named "snake-oil"? The keys are the same on all installations - so there is really no need to recreate them **now**. Anyway: creating new ones is a Good Idea™ .

Comment: Mine randomly broke somehow. I don't know or care how SSL certs work. Just wanted my Postgres to start.

Comment: They aren't the same, they're issued to the hostname.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this one-liner to regenerate both files in one shot.  You'll need to restart Apache after the cert has been re-created.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
```

If you're at all concerned about security (and you should be), then you should regenerate certificates on all affected critical servers, followed by an exhaustive service restart or a system reboot.

If you're just running a play-around box on your LAN that's one thing, but anything you've got on the internet you should definitely reissue.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Will get to the reissing, nice to see a one liner.

Comment: As this is a old question, but has been lifted up again: Today we do have Let's encrypt, which provides free, automated certificates. There's no reason not to use it, if the box is communicating over the public internet.

Comment: Awesome, fixed it for me. Postgres was having issues with it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=803827&p=5140589#post5140589) I found that there is this command:

```
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```

Comment: This solved my isue. Legend!